# In my CURL CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION callback, dltotal is always 0

Tags: php, curl, callback

I've got a CURL progress callback working via the CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION option which is successfully calling my member function in PHP.  The **dlnow** variable is returning a correct received value, but **dltotal** always returns 0.  What am I missing here?

```
class MyClass {

    function getFile(){

    ...

      $fp = fopen ($file, 'w+');
      $curl = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$signed['signed_url']);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1000);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); // write curl response to file
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, array($this, 'curl_progress_callback'));

    }

    function curl_progress_callback($dltotal, $dlnow, $ultotal, $ulnow){
        echo $dltotal; //Reports correct value
        echo $dlnow;   //Always returns 0
    }

}
```

*EDIT: This post has been updated with info from @Sabuj Hassan.  Originally I thought I was receiving a correct dltotal but an incorrect dlnow but I had an additional unnecessary argument in my callback function.*

Answer (score 3):

NOTE: for libcurl older than 7.32.0

the callback function need has the following format

```
curl_progress_callback($resource,$dltotal, $dlnow, $ultotal, $ulnow)
```

where as newer curl binary does not require the resource

```
curl_progress_callback($dltotal, $dlnow, $ultotal, $ulnow)
```

check your curl version version with

```
curl -V
```

Comment: Are you sure its not the other way around with those versions and formats?  Even actual curl docs seem to expect the resource handle to be passed to the callback.  In curl 7.26 im getting a missing arg when $resource is passed, but in 7.35 I don't.

Comment: On libcurl/7.19.7 and PHP 5.6.3, the resource parameter is included.

Comment: How did you understand and where did you read that first (resource) parameter is gone in new libcurl?
I see http://upstream.rosalinux.ru/diffs/libcurl/7.31.0_to_7.32.0/diff.html , https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/include/curl/curl.h there is still also 5 parameters in this function.
So, also
in my PHP 5.6.2, libcurl 7.42.1, Win7 x64 - there are 5 parameters in progress calback function, with first one of resource..

In which cases there's only 4 parameters?

Comment: The PHP docs say the extra parameter was added in PHP 5.5.0. 

"5.5.0. Added the cURL resource as the first argument to the CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION callback."

Answer (score 2):

Try this with removing the class:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, 'curl_progress_callback');
```

Then remove the first parameter from the `callback`.

```
function curl_progress_callback($dltotal, $dlnow, $ultotal, $ulnow){
   ...
}
```

**UPDATE**: A working code: Try to run it from your end.

```
function getFile(){
  $fp = fopen ("output.html", 'w+');
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.mashable.com/');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1000);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, 'curl_progress_callback');

  $result = curl_exec($curl);
  fclose($fp);

}

function curl_progress_callback($dltotal, $dlnow, $ultotal, $ulnow){
    echo "$dltotal\n";
    echo "$dlnow\n";
}

getFile();
```

Comment: Removing the class doesn't work - having the array with the class in the call is essential to get the callback to be called at all since we're in a class function.  That part is working fine.  

The problem is that CURL isn't sending any data back in the arguments. Removing the first parameter I was able to get a response for some URLs but not others - what might determine this?

Comment: I'm receiving the $dlnow value but $dltotal is always 0.

Comment: if it works, then it should work for every url. May be you are doing something wrong. Update your question with the new version of your code.

Comment: I suspect that the sending site is not sending me the content-length and that is why I'm not consistently getting the dltotal. The only difference with my new code is removing the first parameter of the callback as you indicated.

Comment: @Oddible check the updated answer, and try to run it from your end.

Comment: Thanks @Subuj but your code is now identical to mine except yours doesn't have the array() in the CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION so it cannot work as a member of a class - that setting must be as I've done it or it won't call the callback function since they're both class member functions.  The problem is resolved in that the website I'm accessing doesn't seem to be setting the http content-length attribute which is why the dltotal is always blank - seems to be a server-side issue.  Thank you for resolving the issue I had with improper curl_progress_callback arguments.

Answer (score 1):

We can simplify to

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION,
            static function ($dltotal, $dlnow, $ultotal, $ulnow){
                print_r([$dltotal, $dlnow, $ultotal, $ulnow]);
            });
```

Or even the following which is cross version compatible.

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION,
            static function (...$args){
                print_r($args);
            });
```

Finally,

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION,
            static fn(...$args) => print_r($args));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the website I'm requesting isn't sending an http content-length so dltotal is always empty.  Thanks to @Subuj Hassan for correcting my error in my curl_progress_callback which had one too many values and made me originally think that the issue was with the dlnow value.

Answer (score 0):

Use **CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION** callback:-

```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION,  function( $source, $download_size, $downloaded, $upload_size, $uploaded){
     //code here        
  });
```